# Can't compile lambda without "const" in the parameter list

Tags: c++, lambda

```
#include <stack>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

void biggies(vector<string>& str,vector<string>::size_type sz)
{
    sort(str.begin(),str.end());
    auto end_unique=unique(str.begin(), str.end());
    str.erase(end_unique,str.end());

//When I remove the "const" in the parameter list, the code can't compile 
    stable_sort(str.begin(), str.end(), [](const string&a,const string&b){return a.size()<b.size();});

    auto wc=find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [sz](string& a){return a.size()>=sz;});
    for_each(wc, str.end(), [](string& s){cout<<s<<endl;});

}

int main()
{
    vector<string>vec{"11","22","1","1111","2222","2","111","222"};
    biggies(vec, 2);
}
```

I test the code in Xcode 6.4 and Visual Studio 2015 and it turns out that both cannot compile without the "const" in the parameter list. I wonder why the lack of "const" would disrupt the compilation? I'll be very thankful with your answers.

Comment: Can you add what you get when trying to compile it?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for a comparator to change the things it compares, so I at least the compilation error is a *good thing*.

Comment: @MKII there're errors in <algorithm >: No matching function for call to object of type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find anything in the standard (N3337) that puts any specific requirements on the parameter types for a comparator passed to sorting-related algorithms. All I can find that kind of hints at why you're having this issue is this:

> 25.4.2: It is assumed that comp will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced
>   iterator.

It is somewhat indirect, but since it is 'assumed' that your comparator won't apply any non-const function to what's given to you by the algorithm, I guess it's valid that the algorithm pass const objects to it; this is likely the source of your problem.